# How to add an app to wishlist though web Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

[Google Play Store](http://play.google.com) lets you add apps to your wishlist, but I can only find the option on Android version (the Play Store app). I often come across apps while browsing on my computer and would like to add them to "wishlist" so I can install them later when I get on my phone.

So, how can I add an Android app to my wishlist from computer web browser (instead of Android Play Store app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an Android app to your wishlist from computer web browser by clicking on the "Wishlist" button just next to "Install" or "Buy" button.

[image: Play Store screen shot]

To access you wishlist from the browser being signed in you have to click on the "Settings" button (upper right corner, gear icon) and choose My Orders option from the drop down list. Next on the left hand side under "Apps", "Movies", "Music" etc you will find My Wishlist option. Click on that option to see/modify your wishlist.